# Dismiss UIActionSheet by tapping darkened area on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I have a UIPickerView inside an UIActionSheet. Is it possible to just tap the darkened area and dismiss the UIActionSheet along with the UIPickerView? If not how do I add a cancel button?

I need to do all this programmatically.

Comment: The `UIActionView` view is not meant to contain `UIPickerView` subviews. Why wouldn't you just slide in the `UIPickerView` from the bottom, and draw the darkened area yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think adding a UIPickerView in an UIActionSheet is that great of a decision but I guess a touch event on the view would do the trick:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //Code to dismiss stuff here, like:
    //[myPickerView setHidden:YES];
}
```